# htaccess deny all and cron'd file

Tags: php, .htaccess

So if I have htaccess deny all on a given folder, but the file we have inside the folder we would like to cron every few hours, are there extra considerations I need to make, or does deny all not apply to this situation?

Comment: how are you calling the scripts via cron?

Answer (score 3):

if the cron job executes the php file directly through the php interpreter, then no, it never goes through the webserver and any webserver settings or configurations are irrelevant.

But, if the cron job executes a web browser or something like wget, making an http request through the webserver, then yes, you'll have a problem. You could have the webserver allow requests from local ips.

Comment: Chris, could you provide an example of how I have the cron execute the php file directly through the interpreter?? Right now we are indeed using wget.

Comment: the cron command should contain something like `/full/path/to/php /full/path/to/script.php` the environment your script runs in is different. Possibly different php version, diff predefined variables, diff file paths, diff php.ini and more. use full file paths and start with a hello world script from the command line, gradually building up to your real script, employing good debugging techniques the whole time. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php